# Importing Jython into a JavaFX application

Tags: javafx, jython, module-info

I am trying to add Python functionality to a javaFX application using Jython (with Maven in the IntelliJ IDE). To do this used the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

My module-info:

```
module com.example.application {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.sql;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires jython;

    opens Example.application.main to javafx.fxml;
    exports Example.application.main;
}
```

The problem that I am encountering occured in the aforementioned module-info; when I attempted to run the application, I was given the following error message:

```
java: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Module jython contains package org.w3c.dom.html, module jdk.xml.dom exports package org.w3c.dom.html to jython
```

I have tried to exclude the part of the jython library that caused the problem by excluding it in the dependency, but this had no effect (I probably did not perform this function in a satisfactory manner due to my illiteracy in Maven).

If anybody here in the Jython community has come across this error before, how did you go about resolving the issue?

Comment: ... an [open thread](https://github.com/jython/jython/issues/28) on GitHub related to this.

Comment: It seems that the version of jython you are trying to use is not built to work well with the Java module system.  Instead, delete your module info and create a non-modular application (which uses the JavaFX and JDK modules but does not define a module for your own application).  Instructions on creating non-modular JavaFX applications are in [getting started at openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).  Additionally (and unrelated), I recommend a minimum version of 21 for JavaFX.